# How can I display an image in a Treeview Row? Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter, mariadb

I'm making a registration and databse system for a car company. To display the infomration i'm making a table with a treeview, and in the last column of the table I need to place a picture of the car. The image is being retrieve from a database using mariaDB. I'm able to retrieve the image and displayed on a label outside the treeview. But for some reason the image is not being displayed correctly on the treeview, instead of going into the last column and of the corresponding row is going to the last row of the first column. Btw the image is only being displayed when I double click on the specific vehicle because I wasn't able to make it appear when I make the query for the database data.  [View of how the image is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2YvM.png)

```
# Importando librerias necesarias
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import mariadb
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64

# Clase para registar los vehiculos


class Vehiculo:
    def __init__(self, registro):
        # Creando y configurando ventana con un contructor
        self.registro = registro
        self.registro.title("Registar Vehiculo")
        self.registro.geometry("1580x900")
        self.registro.resizable(True, False)
        self.registro.config()

        # Combo box para elegir los años
        years = []
        for year in range(1990, 2024):
            years.append(year)
        year_var = tk.StringVar()
        # Opciones para el combo box para el color
        colores = ["Blanco", "Negro", "Gris", "Rojo", "Azul", "Verde", "Amarillo"]
        color_var = tk.StringVar()

        # Variable para foto
        self.foto = None

        # Labels de los datos a registrar

        # Frames para ingresar datos
        frame_registro = ttk.LabelFrame(
            master=self.registro, text="Registrando Vehiculo"
        )
        frame_registro.grid(column=0, rowspan=15)
        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="Marca: ").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            columnspan=1,
        )
        frame_2 = ttk.Frame(master=self.registro)
        frame_2.grid(column=0, rowspan=5)
        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="Modelo: ").grid(
            row=1, column=0, columnspan=1
        )

        # Creando el menu
        self.menu_bar = ttk.Menu(master=self.registro)

        # Creando el menu archivo
        self.archivo_menu = ttk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.archivo_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=self.registro.quit)

        # Creando el menu Opciones
        self.opciones_menu = ttk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.opciones_menu.add_command(
            label="Buscar Registro", command=self.ventanaBuscar
        )

        # Agregando los menus a la barra menu
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=self.archivo_menu)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Opciones", menu=self.opciones_menu)

        # Configurando el menu en la ventana principal
        self.registro.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="Año: ").grid(
            row=2, column=0, columnspan=1
        )
        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="No. Serie: ").grid(
            row=3, column=0, columnspan=1
        )
        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="Color: ").grid(
            row=4, column=0, columnspan=1
        )
        ttk.Label(master=frame_registro, text="Tipo: ").grid(
            row=5, column=0, columnspan=1
        )
        ttk.Label(master=frame_2, text="Foto: ").grid(
            row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1
        )
        self.mensaje = ttk.Label(master=frame_2, text="", foreground="green")
        self.mensaje.grid(row=17, columnspan=2)

        # Entrys de los datos a registrar
        self.marca = ttk.Entry(master=frame_registro)
        self.marca.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.marca.focus()

        self.modelo = ttk.Entry(master=frame_registro)
        self.modelo.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.ano = ttk.Combobox(
            master=frame_registro, textvariable=year_var, values=years
        )
        self.ano.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.no_serie = ttk.Entry(master=frame_registro)
        self.no_serie.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.color = ttk.Combobox(
            master=frame_registro, values=colores, textvariable=color_var
        )
        self.color.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

        # RadioButton alv
        # self.tipo = ttk.Combobox(master=frame_registro, values=tipos, textvariable=tipo_var)
        self.tipos_var = tk.StringVar()
        # (SUV, Hatchback, Crossover, Convertible, Sedan, Sport, Minivan, Pickup)
        opciones = [
            "SUV",
            "Hatchback",
            "Crossover",
            "Convertible",
            "Sedan",
            "Sport",
            "Minivan",
            "Pickup",
        ]

        for opcion in opciones:
            self.tipo = ttk.Radiobutton(
                master=frame_registro,
                text=opcion,
                value=opcion,
                variable=self.tipos_var,
            )
            self.tipo.grid(column=1, pady=5, padx=5, rowspan=8)

        ttk.Button(
            master=frame_2, text="Seleccionar foto", command=self.abrirImagen
        ).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, rowspan=1)

        # Botones para editar, guardar, buscar y eliminar
        self.buton_reg = ttk.Button(
            master=frame_2,
            text="Registrar Vehiculo",
            command=self.agregarRegistro,
        )
        self.buton_reg.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5, rowspan=1)

        self.buton_edit = ttk.Button(
            master=frame_2, text="Editar Vehiculo", command=self.editarRegistro
        )
        self.buton_edit.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5, rowspan=1)
        self.buton_edit["state"] = "disabled"

        self.buton_delete = ttk.Button(
            master=frame_2, text="Borrar Vehiculo", command=self.borrarRegistro
        )
        self.buton_delete.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5, rowspan=1)
        self.buton_delete["state"] = "disabled"

        self.buton_foto = ttk.Button(
            master=frame_2, text="Ver Imagen", command=self.mostrarImagen
        )
        # self.buton_foto.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Treeview para desplegar los vehiculos registrados
        columns = ("marca", "modelo", "año", "serie", "color", "tipo", "foto")

        self.tabla_vehiculos = ttk.Treeview(self.registro, columns=columns)
        self.tabla_vehiculos.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=7, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.tabla_vehiculos.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.doubleClick)

        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#0", text="Marca:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#1", text="Modelo:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#2", text="Año:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#3", text="No. Serie:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#4", text="Color:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#5", text="Tipo:", anchor="w")
        self.tabla_vehiculos.heading("#6", text="Foto:", anchor="w")

        # Label para desplegar imagen
        self.imagen_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(master=self.registro, text="Foto:")
        self.imagen_frame.grid(
            row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2, sticky="w" + "e"
        )
        self.imagen_label = ttk.Label(master=self.imagen_frame, text="fotos", image="")

        self.imagen_label.grid(
            row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2, sticky=("w", "e")
        )

        # Funciones

    def abrirImagen(self):
        filename = askopenfilename()
        if filename:
            try:
                # Leer el archivo de imagen en modo binario
                with open(filename, "rb") as file:
                    image_data = file.read()

                # Convertir la imagen a formato base64
                image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data)

                # Imprimir los datos de la imagen en formato base64
                # print(image_base64)

                # Aquí puedes realizar la inserción en la base de datos
                # utilizando los datos de la imagen en formato BLOB
                # ...
                self.foto = image_data
            except IOError as e:
                print(f"Error al leer la imagen: {e}")

    def connectDatabase(self):
        try:
            connection = mariadb.connect(
                user="root",
                password="",
                host="localhost",
                database="agencia",
            )
            print("Connected to the database")
            return connection
        except mariadb.Error as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to the database: {e}")
            return None

    def mostrarImagen(self):
        conection = self.connectDatabase()
        if conection is None:
            return
        try:
            cursor = conection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                f"SELECT `numero de serie`, `foto` FROM `vehiculos` WHERE `numero de serie` = {self.no_serieViejo}"
            )
            record = cursor.fetchone()

            if record is not None:
                id_, image_data = record
                image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
                image = image.resize((400, 300), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

                # Insert the item into the Treeview with the image
                item = self.tabla_vehiculos.insert("", tk.END, image=photo)

                # Set the image attribute for the inserted item
                self.tabla_vehiculos.set(item, "foto", photo)

                # Store reference to the photo in the Treeview widget
                self.tabla_vehiculos.photo = photo

                # Update the image displayed in the photo_label
                self.imagen_label["image"] = photo

        except mariadb.Error as e:
            print(f"Error retrieving image: {e}")

    # Funcion para consultar los vehiculos de la BDD
    def consultaVehiculo(self, query):
        try:
            conn = mariadb.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password="",
                database="agencia",
                autocommit=True,
            )

            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            return cur
        except mariadb.Error as e:
            print("Error al conectarse a la base de datos", e)

    # Funcion para mostrar los datos de los vehiculos registrados
    def mostrarDatos(self, where=""):
        registros = self.tabla_vehiculos.get_children()
        for registro in registros:
            self.tabla_vehiculos.delete(registro)

        # cur = self.consultaVehiculo("SELECT `marca`, `modelo`, `año`, `numero de serie`, `color`, `Tipo` FROM `vehiculos`")

        if len(where) > 0:
            cur = self.consultaVehiculo(
                "SELECT `marca`, `modelo`, `año`, `numero de serie`, `color`, `Tipo` FROM `vehiculos` "
                + where
            )
        else:
            cur = self.consultaVehiculo(
                "SELECT `marca`, `modelo`, `año`, `numero de serie`, `color`, `Tipo` FROM `vehiculos` "
            )

        for marca, modelo, ano, serie, color, tipo in cur:
            self.tabla_vehiculos.insert(
                "", 0, text=marca, values=(modelo, ano, serie, color, tipo)
            )

    # Funcion para agregar el registro a la BDD
    def agregarRegistro(self):
        if (
            len(self.marca.get()) != 0
            and len(self.modelo.get()) != 0
            and len(self.ano.get()) != 0
            and len(self.no_serie.get()) != 0
            and len(self.color.get()) != 0
            and len(self.tipos_var.get()) != 0
        ):
            query = f"INSERT INTO `vehiculos`(`marca`, `modelo`, `año`, `numero de serie`, `color`, `Tipo`) VALUES ('{self.marca.get()}','{self.modelo.get()}','{self.ano.get()}','{self.no_serie.get()}','{self.color.get()}','{self.tipos_var.get()}');"
            self.consultaVehiculo(query)
            self.mensaje[
                "text"
            ] = f"El vehiculo marca {self.marca.get()}, \nmodelo {self.modelo.get()} se ha agregado \nexitosamente"
            self.marca.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.modelo.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.ano.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.no_serie.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.color.delete(0, tk.END)
            # self.tipo.delete(0, tk.END)

            self.marca.focus()
            self.mostrarDatos()
            # print(self.foto)
        else:
            self.mensaje[
                "text"
            ] = "**Ningun dato debe de estar vacio, \nasegurate que todos los \ndatos esten completos"
            self.mensaje["foreground"] = "red"

    # Funcion para editar el registro a la BDD
    def editarRegistro(self):
        if (
            len(self.marca.get()) != 0
            and len(self.modelo.get()) != 0
            and len(self.ano.get()) != 0
            and len(self.no_serie.get()) != 0
            and len(self.color.get()) != 0
            and len(self.tipos_var.get()) != 0
        ):
            query = f"UPDATE `vehiculos` SET `marca`='{self.marca.get()}',`modelo`='{self.modelo.get()}',`año`='{self.ano.get()}',`numero de serie`='{self.no_serie.get()}',`color`='{self.color.get()}',`Tipo`='{self.tipos_var.get()}' WHERE `numero de serie`={self.no_serieViejo}"
            self.consultaVehiculo(query)
            self.mensaje[
                "text"
            ] = f"El vehiculo marca {self.marca.get()}, \nmodelo {self.modelo.get()} se ha actulizado \nexitosamente"
            self.marca.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.modelo.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.ano.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.no_serie.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.color.delete(0, tk.END)
            # self.tipo.delete(0, tk.END)

            self.marca.focus()
            self.mostrarDatos()
            self.buton_reg["state"] = "normal"
            self.buton_edit["state"] = "disable"
            self.buton_delete["state"] = "disable"
        else:
            self.mensaje[
                "text"
            ] = "**Ningun dato debe de estar vacio, \nasegurate que todos los \ndatos esten completos"
            self.mensaje["foreground"] = "red"

    # Funcion para borrar registro de la BDD
    def borrarRegistro(self):
        if (
            messagebox.askyesno(
                message="Seguro de borrar el registro?",
                title=f"Eliminar Vehiculo: {self.marca.get()}, {self.modelo.get()}",
            )
            == True
        ):
            query = f"DELETE FROM `vehiculos` WHERE `numero de serie`= '{self.no_serieViejo}'"
            self.consultaVehiculo(query)
            self.mensaje[
                "text"
            ] = f"El vehiculo {self.marca.get()}, {self.modelo.get()} \nse ha elimindao\nexitosamente"
            self.marca.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.modelo.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.ano.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.no_serie.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.color.delete(0, tk.END)
            # self.tipo.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.marca.focus()
            self.mostrarDatos()
            self.marca.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.modelo.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.ano.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.no_serie.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.color.delete(0, tk.END)
            # self.tipo.delete(0, tk.END)

            self.buton_reg["state"] = "normal"
            self.buton_edit["state"] = "disable"
            self.buton_delete["state"] = "disable"

    # Funcion para hacer doble click en la tabla

    def doubleClick(self, event):
        self.no_serieViejo = str(
            self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][2]
        )
        self.marca.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.modelo.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.ano.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.no_serie.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.color.delete(0, tk.END)
        # self.tipo.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.buton_reg["state"] = "disable"
        self.buton_edit["state"] = "normal"
        self.buton_delete["state"] = "normal"
        self.marca.insert(
            0, str(self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["text"])
        )
        self.modelo.insert(
            0,
            str(
                self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][0]
            ),
        )
        self.ano.insert(
            0,
            str(
                self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][1]
            ),
        )
        self.no_serie.insert(
            0,
            str(
                self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][2]
            ),
        )
        self.color.insert(
            0,
            str(
                self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][3]
            ),
        )

        self.mostrarImagen()
        # self.tipos_var.insert(0,str(self.tabla_vehiculos.item(self.tabla_vehiculos.selection())["values"][4]),)

    # Funcion para abrir una nueva ventana

    def ventanaBuscar(self):
        # Creando nueva ventana con un toplevel
        buscar_ventana = ttk.Toplevel()
        buscar_ventana.title("Buscar Registro")
        buscar_ventana.geometry("400x180")
        buscar_ventana.resizable(False, False)

        # Creando label frame para ingresar los datos de busqueda
        frame_buscar = ttk.LabelFrame(master=buscar_ventana, text="Buscar")
        frame_buscar.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Creando labels para los campos de busqueda
        ttk.Label(master=frame_buscar, text="Buscar por marca").grid(
            row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5
        )
        ttk.Label(master=frame_buscar, text="Buscar por numero de serie").grid(
            row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5
        )

        # Creando los entrys para los campos de busqueda
        self.buscarMarca = ttk.Entry(master=frame_buscar)
        self.buscarMarca.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.buscarNo_serie = ttk.Entry(master=frame_buscar)
        self.buscarNo_serie.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Creando boton buscar
        self.buscar_boton = ttk.Button(
            master=frame_buscar, text="Buscar Vehiculo", command=self.buscarRegistro
        )
        self.buscar_boton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Funcion para buscar un registro

    def buscarRegistro(self):
        where = "where 1=1"
        if len(self.buscarMarca.get()) > 0:
            where = f" {where} and marca = '{self.buscarMarca.get()}'"
        if len(self.buscarNo_serie.get()) > 0:
            where = f" {where} and `numero de serie` = '{self.buscarNo_serie.get()}'"
        self.mostrarDatos(where)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Creando y configurando ventana con un contructor
    registro = ttk.Window(themename="darkly")
    aplicacion = Vehiculo(registro)
    aplicacion.mostrarDatos()
    registro.mainloop()
```

The image should be displayed on the last column of the table in the respecting row, but every time I change anything the image is not displaying, not even on the label for some reason. I honestly don't know much about databases so I'm kinda of lost.

Comment: Why do you think that the image should be shown on the last column of the treeview?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following updates to display image in last column.
For adding the image on the last column you need to make some changes in the code as

**You need to remove this line of code**
#Insert the item into the Treeview with the image
item = self.tabla_vehiculos.insert("", tk.END, image=photo)

**Also modify this function**
for marca, modelo, ano, serie, color, tipo in cur:
self.tabla_vehiculos.insert(
"", 0, text=marca, values=(modelo, ano, serie, color, tipo ""))